# AWSIoTPythonSDK publishTimeoutException

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, iot, aws-iot

I want to publish back once i get a get a data from Subscribe topic. However when i do so, AWSIoTPythonSDK throws exception stating publishTimeoutException.

I configured `ConnectDisconnectTimeout` and `MQTTOperationTimeout` but cannot totally avoid timeout.

How to prevent this ? Thank you

Comment: Please read the [docs](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) about what a good question needs for people to be able to help. You need to edit the question to show the code and the actual error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be an issue with the IoT Thing policy. Make sure that the IoT Thing certificate's policy has permissions to publish to your desired topic.

Comment: and I knew that.  Thanks for reminding me